# selenium web driver eclipse connection error

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and Junit. Since yesterday, trying to run Selenium script in eclipse. However, I am getting this error

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Any idea?

I uninstalled and installed eclipse
redownloaded and installed the jdk
but the error did not change, http://i.imgur.com/OQc5BvC.png?1
Could you give another idea please, I stucked in this situation and can not continue to study

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse directory and start eclipse from cmd by executing the following command:

```
eclipse -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Please lemme know if this solve your issue.